# Vertical ScrollBar not working

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, treeview

I want to use a vertical scroll bar to my treeview list.
The items on the treeview are added programmatically, using a list.

Here is the code I already have.

```
<TreeViewItem Name="tree" Height="99" Margin="2,0,0,171" Grid.Row="2" Background="Aqua"
                              Header="Tags" ScrollBar.Scroll="tree_Scroll" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

    private void tree_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(tree, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
    }
```

Comment: You might need to add the xaml for the container, because the scroll bar behavior is affected by the cntainer and the control itself.

Comment: `<ScrollBar Name="scroll" Orientation="Vertical" Height="33" Background="LightSalmon" ScrollBar.Scroll="tree_Scroll" 
                               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                               Margin="0,0,310,237" Grid.Row="2"
                               Minimum="1" Maximum="240"/>`

Comment: that information? but where? inside treeview?

Comment: Are you sure you're not having a _typo_? Cause I'm seeing `<TreeViewItem>` tag, not a `<TreeView>` tag...

Comment: Nice Point! Gonna edit this! Thanks lol